# How do I combine variables of a row and column?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-dates

I have dates set up in column A in yearmonthday format (ex. 20210101), types of product in column B (there are 8 that repeat throughout, so the same date is repeated in column A for 8 rows), and hours 1-24 in chronological order in columns C1-Z1 (ex. HR 1 C1, HR 2 D1, HR3 D3, etc.) The rest of the cells contain values that the product is worth for each corresponding product on a corresponding date and hour (ex. C2 is for X product during hour 1 on 20210101, C3 is for Y product during hour 1 on 20210101, D1 is for X product during hour 2 on 20210101.)

I want to reformat this spreadsheet to make the products as a row, and instead combine the date column and hour column. So, ideally, I'd want for example A2 labeled as 20210101 HR 1, A3 as 20210101 HR 2, etc. Then, B2 would be the value of X product for 20210101 HR 1,C2 would be the value of Y product for 20210101 HR 1, B3 would be the value of X product for 20210101 HR 2, etc.

How might I go about doing this?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/171551/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [unpivot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76199023/13045193) pattern with `query()`. Choose **Insert > Sheet** and put this formula in cell `A1` of the new sheet:

```
=let( 
  unpivot_, lambda(d,f,g,let(r_,lambda(t,o,h,chooserows(t,sequence(h,1,o))),c_,lambda(t,o,w,choosecols(t,sequence(1,w,o))),s_,lambda(r,c,h,w,r_(c_(d,c,w),r,h)),l_,lambda(c,s_(1,c,1,1)),hr,hstack(s_(1,1,1,f),"Hour","Value"),i,sequence(1,(columns(d)-f)/g,f+1,g),n,tocol(æ,2),reduce(hr,sequence(rows(d)-1,1,2),lambda(z,r,let(e,s_(r,1,1,f),s,reduce(n,i,lambda(t,c,let(x,s_(r,c,1,g),if(single(x)="",t,vstack(t,hstack(e,l_(c),x)))))),vstack(z,s)))))), 

  query( 
    unpivot_(Sheet1!A1:Z, 2, 1), 
    "select Col1, Col3, max(Col4) 
     group by Col1, Col3 
     pivot Col2", 
    1 
  ) 
)
```

With data like this:

| Date | Product | HR 01 | HR 02 | HR 03 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20210101 | product X | 23 | 47 | 12 | ... |
| 20210101 | product Y | 40 | 28 | 9 | ... |
| 20210101 | product Z3 | 12 | 23 | 43 | ... |
| 20210101 | product Z4 | 22 | 44 | 29 | ... |
| 20210101 | product Z5 | 28 | 9 | 37 | ... |

...the results look like this:

| Date | Hour | product X | product Y | product Z3 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20210101 | HR 01 | 23 | 40 | 12 | ... |
| 20210101 | HR 02 | 47 | 28 | 23 | ... |
| 20210101 | HR 03 | 12 | 9 | 43 | ... |
| 20210101 | HR 04 | 36 | 43 | 30 | ... |
| 20210101 | HR 05 | 7 | 13 | 37 | ... |
| 20210101 | HR 06 | 43 | 5 | 24 | ... |

If need be, the result table can be further processed with an array formula to concatenate the date and hour, like this:

```
=arrayformula(hstack(A1:A & " " & B1:B, C1:J))
```